# Check if product's category's or its child's page is being displayed in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In a woocommerce store there are multiple product categories, f.x. `toys, clothes, shoes, adults` which have a few child categories each. The products from `adults` category have to be blurred if it is not  the `adults` or its child category that is being displayed.

What I do in the loop for now is this:

```
   $for_adults = has_term( 106, 'product_cat' );

   if( $for_adults  && !is_product_category( 'adults' )){
         echo '<img src="'.$image_src.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" class="product-image blur" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
   }else{
         echo '<img src="'.$image_src.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" class="product-image" title="'.get_the_title().'">';
   }
```

The problem is that `is_product_category( 'adults' )`, only returns true for when the exact category is being displayed and what needs to be done is that it would return true for when child categories pages are being displayed without hard-coding the category slugs.

Any help or gudance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// Get the term
$for_adults = get_term_by( 'slug', 'adults', 'product_cat' );

// Get the term ancestors
$product_parent_categories_all_hierachy = get_ancestors( $for_adults->term_id, 'product_cat' );

$parent_is_adults = false;

foreach ( $product_parent_categories_all_hierachy as $ancestor_id) {
    if ( $for_adults->term_id == $ancestor_id) {
        $parent_is_adults = true;
        break;
    }
}


if ( is_product_category( 'adults' ) || $parent_is_adults) {

    echo '<img src="'.$image_src.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" class="product-image blur" title="'.get_the_title().'">';

} else {

    echo '<img src="'.$image_src.'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" class="product-image" title="'.get_the_title().'">';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

@0blongCode the code works fine :) but if the debug mode is on, the following notice appears:

> Notice: Undefined variable: category in […] on line […] Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in […] on line […]

To avoid this we only need to change

```
$product_parent_categories_all_hierachy = get_ancestors( $category->term_id, 'product_cat' );
```

to

```
$product_parent_categories_all_hierachy = get_ancestors( $for_adults->term_id, 'product_cat' );
```

Comment: Thanks @futtta, I've adjusted that :)